# how to make pie chart's labelled line bigger than default?

Tags: r

I would like to make line longer and different in angle of printed sliced labelled line.

Note: I am not talking about `clockwise = TRUE`.

code:

```
pie.sales <- c(0.12, 0.3, 0.26, 0.16, 0.04, 0.12)
names(pie.sales) <- c("Blueberry", "Cherry","Apple", "Boston Cream", "Other", "Vanilla Cream")
pie(pie.sales)
```

Comment: Do you mean the tick mark on the outside?

Comment: ok, these are hard-coded. Have a look at `tail(body(pie))` - you would need to change the `lines` and `text` parts near the bottom to change the tick lengths and reposition the labels accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the length of the line is hard-coded in the function. If you look at the function (just type `pie`), look towards the bottom:

```
function (x, labels = names(x), edges = 200, radius = 0.8, clockwise = FALSE, 
    init.angle = if (clockwise) 90 else 0, density = NULL, angle = 45, 
    col = NULL, border = NULL, lty = NULL, main = NULL, ...) 
{
    if (!is.numeric(x) || any(is.na(x) | x < 0)) 
        stop("'x' values must be positive.")
## ...snip... ##
        if (!is.na(lab) && nzchar(lab)) {
            lines(c(1, 1.05) * P$x, c(1, 1.05) * P$y)
            text(1.1 * P$x, 1.1 * P$y, labels[i], xpd = TRUE, 
                adj = ifelse(P$x < 0, 1, 0), ...)
        }
    }
    title(main = main, ...)
    invisible(NULL)
}
```

You can see the hard-coded 1.05 (twice) for line length, and 1.1 (twice) for text placement. If you take this function, copy it, and redefine it as a new function (perhaps in a `.R` script file), you can fix this for your own use.

Two techniques:

1. You can take the same tact as the original author and code a *different* magic constant into the code; or
2. You can add a couple of options that allow you to control the length of the line and (optionally) the gap between the line and the text.

I've done #2, below. I changed the definition of arguments (within `function(...)`) as well as those two lines towards the bottom, nothing more:

```
mypie <- function (x, labels = names(x), edges = 200, radius = 0.8, clockwise = FALSE, 
    init.angle = if (clockwise) 90 else 0, density = NULL, angle = 45, 
    col = NULL, border = NULL, lty = NULL, main = NULL, len = 0.05, lengap = 0.1, ...) 
{
    if (!is.numeric(x) || any(is.na(x) | x < 0)) 
        stop("'x' values must be positive.")
## ...snip... ##
        if (!is.na(lab) && nzchar(lab)) {
            lines(c(1, 1 + len) * P$x, c(1, 1 + len) * P$y)
            text((1 + len + lengap) * P$x, (1 + len + lengap) * P$y, labels[i], xpd = TRUE, 
                adj = ifelse(P$x < 0, 1, 0), ...)
        }
    }
    title(main = main, ...)
    invisible(NULL)
}
```

With this, you can change your call to something like `mypie(pie.sales, radius = 0.5, len = 0.6, lengap = 0.3)`.
[image: New pie chart]

Now, the next question is how to get the labels aligned better on the ticks, but that's a different question (and will cost you twice as much as you paid for this answer).

**EDIT**

It is possible to have different lengths for each label, perhaps to mitigate overlapping labels. There are perhaps better ways to do it, but a little brute-force and elbow-grease is good for the programmer's soul every now and then ...

Before the `for(i in 1L:nx)` line at the end of the function, add:

```
        list(x = radius * cos(t2p), y = radius * sin(t2p))
    }
    if (length(len) == 1) len <- rep(len, length(x))          # new
    if (length(lengap) == 1) lengap <- rep(lengap, length(x)) # new
    for (i in 1L:nx) { 
        n <- max(2, floor(edges * dx[i]))
```

(First two and last two lines there were supplied for context only.)

Now change the `lines` and `text` lines accordingly (to add per-slice subsetting):

```
        if (!is.na(lab) && nzchar(lab)) {
            lines(c(1, 1 + len[i]) * P$x, c(1, 1 + len[i]) * P$y)
            text((1 + len[i] + lengap[i]) * P$x, (1 + len[i] + lengap[i]) * P$y, labels[i], xpd = TRUE, 
                adj = ifelse(P$x < 0, 1, 0), ...)
        }
```

Now set `len` differently for each slice of the pie, same order:

```
mypie(pie.sales, len = c(0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.25, 0.1, 0.05))
```

[image: New pie chart, take two]

Comment: Could you tell me how to control the overlapped labels ?? mean, how to separate it, if any labels are overlapped one over to others?? This is why i wanted to change angle too.

Comment: If it's enough, will you accept the answer? (Or are you still waiting for "angle"?)

Comment: For a while its enough but you can help me by angel too then it would be more appreciable. Because angle can give me more reliable and elegant figures.

Moreover, i found same problems ( overlapping and angle) in pie3D {plotrix} function that i cant figure it out. Could you please give me any clue for this too as well ??

Thanks once again for your kind help.

Comment: i found Arguments labelrad in pie3D function but its not work for numeric vectors of labels. :(

Comment: Notice in the code that the call to `lines` references `P$x` and `P$y`. The graph is still cartesian with (0,0) at the center of the pie, so those two variables reflect the center of the outer arc of the wedge (iterated over each wedge). Multiplying by a scalar is "straight out" because (0,0) is the other end of the line, but with a little trig you can calculate something from (`P$x`,`P$y`) to a different point based on an angle. Add `angle` as an argument in the function definition: I'd recommend making the angle "relative" instead of "absolute".

Comment: Though perhaps not easy programmatically, you can also change the order of your levels going into the function to control crowding and overlap.